# jQuery Validate rule removal making me cry

Tags: jquery-validate

I am successfully validating and arresting the submission of a form using Validate by the bassistance.de guy.

Problem is, I am halting submission too much as there is a hidden set of inputs which requires validation only if ONE other radio button is checked.

I am calling my validation scheme from a remote script on page load and I was "TRYING" to remove the validation rule on the form page when the contingent element is clicked.

Thing is, the page acts as though the rule is still there.

Here's some pseudo:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="jq.validate.js"></script>
    <script src="formproc.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form method="" action="" id="whatever">
      <input type="radio" name="answer" value="1008" id="yes" /><label for="yes">Yes</yes>
      <input type="radio" name="answer" value="1009" id="no" /><label for="no">No</label>
      <input type="radio" name="answer" value="1010" id="un" /><label for="un">Not sure</label>
      <div id="somedivthatshidden">
        <input type="radio" name="nother" value="1009" id="ok" /><label for="ok">OK</label>
        <input type="radio" name="nother" value="1010" id="noway" /><label for="noway">No Way</label>
      </div>
      <script src="jQ_funx_that_handle_the_show_hide_etc.js"></script>
      <input type="submit" value="doit" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

So, when the user clicks on any of the FIRST 3 radio buttons that DO NOT reveal "SOMEDIVETHATSHIDDEN", I also call for the rule removal.  Is this wrong?

I've tried putting the rule removal inline in the document, at the end of my function listing, so on and so forth... no dice.  Still hangs on that required second set of radios even if they're not displayed

Thanks much,
Rob

Comment: For someone else to be able to answer this, they'd also need a [minimal sample](http://sscce.org/) of your validation script.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [depends config option](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions) to make a field conditionally required.